# Fill a column with data from other others, conditional on another column in r

Tags: r

I have a df as below columns ID:D, and I would like to create column E.
Column E should be conditionally filled by the character data in columns A, B and C based on the instruction from column D.

| ID | A | B | C | D | **E** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | tsg | tlm | NA | 1 | **tsg** |
| t2 | tsg | tlm | NA | 2 | **tlm** |
| t3 | tfp | tsl | tgg | 3 | **tgg** |
| t4 | tsg | tfp | NA | 2 | **tfp** |
| t5 | tlm | NA | NA | 1 | **tlm** |
| t6 | tgg | tlm | NA | 1 | **tgg** |

I have been trying to do it like this but it won't work and I can't understand why.

```
df$E[df$D == 1 ] <- df$A
df$E[df$D == 2 ] <- df$B
df$E[df$D == 3 ] <- df$C
```

If the solution could be in base R I'd also be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cbind` for indexing, i.e.,

```
> transform(df, E = df[-1][cbind(seq_along(D), D)])
  ID   A    B    C D   E
1 t1 tsg  tlm <NA> 1 tsg
2 t2 tsg  tlm <NA> 2 tlm
3 t3 tfp  tsl  tgg 3 tgg
4 t4 tsg  tfp <NA> 2 tfp
5 t5 tlm <NA> <NA> 1 tlm
6 t6 tgg  tlm <NA> 1 tgg
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"), A = c("tsg",
"tsg", "tfp", "tsg", "tlm", "tgg"), B = c("tlm", "tlm", "tsl",
"tfp", NA, "tlm"), C = c(NA, NA, "tgg", NA, NA, NA), D = c(1L,
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), E = c("tsg", "tlm", "tgg", "tfp", "tlm",
"tgg")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding! That's super helpful and definitely works when my data frame looks like this and I can rearrange it to make this solution work.  In reality my dataframe is quite a bit bigger and these columns are not near each other.  I wonder if there's a way of editing so I can use the A B C column names?

Comment: @GDon yes, we can use `df[c("A","B","C")]` instead of `df[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you do it this way you are going to get an error:

```
Warning message:
In df$E[df$D == 1] <- df$A :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

This is because you are trying to replace `df$E[df$D == 1]`, a vector of length 3, with `df$A` with the same row indeces.

You need to do:

```r
df$E[df$D == 1 ] <- df$A[df$D == 1 ]
df$E[df$D == 2 ] <- df$B[df$D == 2 ]
df$E[df$D == 3 ] <- df$C[df$D == 3 ]
```

Alternatively, instead of doing one line per value of `df$D`, to generalise you could do something like:

```r
col_index  <- df$D+1

df$E  <- sapply(seq_along(df), \(i) df[i, col_index[i]])
df
#   ID   A    B    C D   E
# 1 t1 tsg  tlm <NA> 1 tsg
# 2 t2 tsg  tlm <NA> 2 tlm
# 3 t3 tfp  tsl  tgg 3 tgg
# 4 t4 tsg  tfp <NA> 2 tfp
# 5 t5 tlm <NA> <NA> 1 tlm
# 6 t6 tgg  tlm <NA> 1 tgg
```

Comment: Thanks for your speed response @SamR and the explanation, you are right about the problem.  It doesn't like the first solution as it says "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments" - any thoughts?  And the second solution doesn't seem to be working either but it'll have a play.. (its says: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Individual3, value = c("M11", "M11",  : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 47642)

Comment: Are the NAs in column D? How do you want to handle NAs when they occur - do you want column E to be NA? The second solution should still work with NAs - looks like you have another error because of something else going on causing it to select multiple rows. Maybe post a more representative sample of your data?

Comment: Yes in column D, fi there's no instruction from column D (i.e. NA) I want it to carry on being an NA. Do you know how that would work?